# Capturar Url y nombre sesión - Angular

Tags: java, angular, angular7

estoy tratando de capturar la url de cada modulo que ingresa y el usuario de la persona con angular y mandarle al back en este caso es java.
Para realizar unas metricas y ver que usuarios están ingresando seguidamente y que modulo son lo mas vistos.

He creado un **interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'token-usuario':'assasaas'
      });
      const reqClone = req.clone({headers})
      console.log(reqClone);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(this.manejarError)
    )
  }
  manejarError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log('Sucedio un error');
    console.log('Registrando en el log File');
    console.warn(error);
    return throwError('Error Personalizado');
}

}
```

**User.Service**

```
 obtenerUsuario(){
       
        return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/user'/*,{params}*/).pipe(
            map(resp => resp['data'])
        );
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.UserService.obtenerUsuario().subscribe( resp =>{console.log(resp);})
```

**Problema**
Problema es que me devuelve encriptado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**APP.COMPONENT.TS**  : Agregue  registro.registrar(this.constructor.name);

```
import { Component, Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { RoutePartsService } from './core/services/router-parts.service';
import { LayoutService } from './system/frame/services/layout.service';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RegistrarVisitaService } from './services/registrar-visita.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  appTitle = 'MIS';
  pageTitle = '';

  constructor(
    public title: Title,
    private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private routePartsService: RoutePartsService,
    private layout: LayoutService,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private registro: RegistrarVisitaService
  ) {
   registro.registrar(this.constructor.name);
   // registro.registrar('Modulo/NombreDelComponente');
   }
```

Cree un servicio llamado: **RegistrarVisitaService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../core/services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegistrarVisitaService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

  registrar(componente : string){
    console.log(componente);
    this.http.post('url para enviar los datos',
    {
        componente : componente,
        usuario: this.obtenerUsuario()

    }).subscribe(r => {

    });

  }
  private obtenerUsuario(){

    // obtener el usuario logueado
  console.log(this.userService.getEmail())
    return this.userService.getEmail();//'usuarioFalso';
 
   }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el problema ?

Comment: @Lobos cierto me olvide del problema, ahora le coloco

Comment: @Lobos Listo ya lo he editado la pregunta

Comment: Entiendo que se hace una petición a una API en `localhost:8080` y esa url es la que aparece encriptada. Agrega el código donde se hace esa petición junto con la url.

Comment: @Lobos, no soy experto en angular, estoy comenzando en este mundo. bueno estaba indagando y encontre que se podría hacer con interceptores, pero lo que yo quiero realizar es basicamente obtener el url de cada modulo y el usuario y registrarlo en una tabla,ya que quieren saber que modulo y que persona utilizan más, si me podrias ayudar por favor

Comment: Entonces quieres que la app de Angular envíe a un backend la información de cuál módulo está siendo visitado por un usuario? Por ejemplo el usuario entra al módulo de ventas, entonces la app envía al backend la url `*/ventas` y el usuario `juan`? Y conforme el usuario navega dentro de la app así se registran los módulos que está visitando.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113845/discussion-between-lobos-and-pierodev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crear un servicio que se conecte al router de Angular para obtener información de los eventos de navegación:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationStart,Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RegistrarService {

  // insertar una instancia del router en el servicio
  constructor(private router: Router) { 

    // suscribirse a los eventos de navegación
    // así se obtendrá información cada vez que se navegue en la aplicación
    router.events.subscribe(e => {
      // obtener la url navegada con la propiedad url del router
      
      // los eventos de navegación son varios así que se filtra solo uno
      if(e instanceof NavigationStart){
         this.registrar(this.router.url);
      }
     
    });
  }

  private registrar(url : string){
   
    console.log(url);

  }

  private getUsuarioLogueado(){

    return 'usuario 1';

  }

}
```

En el `app.component` agregar una instancia del servicio en el constructor:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  

  constructor(private registrar: RegistrarService){
    
  }
}
```

Con ese par de cambios la aplicación puede capturar cada url en la que se está navegando.

Comment: una consulta como puedo obtener el nombre dl modulo dinamico :  registro.registrar('Modulo/NombreDelComponente');

Comment: Con `this.constructor.name` puedes obtener el nombre del componente.

Comment: agregue this.constructor.name en el app.component.ts y cuando navego y cambio de modulo sigue apareciendo el app.component.ts , edite mi pregunta al final y es lo que he realizado, veo que no cambia el nombre del modulo

Comment: Sí. Debes hacer lo mismo en todos los componentes para que registre el ingreso.

Comment: he notado que aqui hay un modulo generido para todos pero hay un routing.module.ts que lo tiene como path.

{
        path: 'not-asig',
        component: ReportCraV1p1Component,
        data: { title: "Cartera No Asignada",
                report: "rda/administracion/cartera/cartera_noasignada" }
      },
      {
        path: 'mon-desem',
        component: ReportCraV1p1Component,
        data: { title: "Monitor Metas Desembolso",
                report: "avance/monitor_metas_desembolso" }
      }

Comment: Buen dato. Haré una solución un poco más elaborada usando el modulo de `routing`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113877/discussion-between-lobos-and-pierodev).

Comment: muchas gracias mi amigo, te lo agradezco

Comment: muchas gracias lo probare, aya si es cierto ya no es necesario ahora si lo agarra, aunque he notado que cuando inicia sesión bueno la página le manda a esta url: com/rda/adm/mon-desem pero en el console no sale nada, ahora si me voy a otro modulo com/rda/adm/cmg-cart en el console recien se visualiza la url anterior y no la actual: